# Getting Values from nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, return-value

I need to get data from dictionary that is in format like this :

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> MyDictionary = new    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
{
    {"HEIGHT", new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"table", "TR_HEIGHT"}, {"prefix", "HEI"}}},
    {"WEIGHT", new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"table", "TR_WEIGHT"}, {"prefix", "WIL"}}},
    {"LENGTH", new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"table", "TR_LENGTH"}, {"prefix", "LEN"}}},
};
```

It is posible to if I insert "HEIGHT" i get back prefix is "HEI" and table is "TR_HEIGHT"?

Thank's

Comment: If the keys are known to always exist: `var prefix = MyDictionary["HEIGHT"]["prefix"];`

Comment: That code does not compile

Comment: `It is posible to if I insert "HEIGHT" i get back prefix is "HEI" and table is "TR_HEIGHT"?`
Please clearify.

Comment: @Alberto The code only didn't compile because of a missed quote (easy to do if the code was manually typed into the editor), you could have fixed it.

Comment: Its work great, tank you @Adam Houldsworth for fast answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is posible to if I insert "HEIGHT" i get back prefix is "HEI" and
>   table is "TR_HEIGHT"?

Yes

```
Dictionary<string, string> heightAttr = MyDictionary["HEIGHT"];
string table  = heightAttr["table"];    //  TR_HEIGHT
string prefix = heightAttr["prefix"];   //  HEI
```